# Extract and sort a large text file

Tags: powershell

I have wrote some lines of codes that extracts information for a large text file. However, it takes days to complete. Is there a better and faster way to do it?

These are some of the lines in sna.txt. There are thousands of lines and the file is about 100MB.

```
WORKSTATION GGGGGG /ADD                         \

  /COMMENT:"GGG111"                             \

  /WKSTAONLY:Yes                                  \

  /ADDRESS:No                                     \

  /IPSUBNET:No                                    \

WORKSTATION GGGGGG                              \

  /INSERT:GGG222                                \

WORKSTATION GGGGGG                              \

  /INSERT:GGG333                                \

WORKSTATION GGGGGG                              \

  /INSERT:GGG444                                \

WORKSTATION GGGGGG                              \

  /INSERT:GGG555                               \

WORKSTATION HHHHHH /ADD                         \

  /COMMENT:"HHH111"                             \

  /WKSTAONLY:Yes                                  \

  /ADDRESS:No                                     \

  /IPSUBNET:No                                    \

WORKSTATION HHHHHH                              \

  /INSERT:HHH222                                \

WORKSTATION HHHHHH                              \

  /INSERT:HHH333
```

Here is my code

```
$SNAContent = $SNADevices = $snacomputerlist = $snacomputers = $null
$snasorted = '\\xxx\yyy\snasorted.txt'
$snacomputers = '\\xxx\yyy\snacomputers.txt'
$SNAPath = '\\xxx\yyy\sna.txt'
$SNAContent = Get-Content $SNACFGPath
$SNAContent | Select-String -Pattern '(WORKSTATION.*/ADD)' | ForEach-Object {
    $_ -replace "WORKSTATION" -replace "/ADD" -replace "\\" -replace " "
} | Out-File $snacfgcomputers -Append

Get-Content $snacfgcomputers | Where-Object {
    ($_ -notmatch 'aaaaaaaa') -or
    ($_ -notmatch 'bbbbbbbb')
} | Set-Content $snacfgcomputers

$snacomputerlist = Get-Content $snacomputers

$snacomputerlist | ForEach-Object {
    (($SNAContent | Select-String -Pattern $_ -Context 0,1 | ForEach-Object {
        $_.Context.PostContext[0].Trim() -replace "/COMMENT:" -replace "/INSERT:" -replace "\\"
    }) -join "," -replace " ","").Insert(0,"$_,") | Out-File $snacfgsorted -Append
}
```

This is the result in snasorted.txt

```
GGGGGG,"GGG111",GGG222,GGG333,GGG444,GGG555
HHHHHH,"HHH111",HHH222,HHH333
```

Comment: PLEASE, put your sample data and your code into _two different code formatting blocks_ so that they are both readable. [*grin*]

Comment: What are these?  `$SNACFGPath $snacfgcomputers $snacfgsorted`

Comment: Something like this is faster, but uses more memory:  `$a = get-content -readcount -1 file; $b = $a | sort; set-content file2 $b`

Comment: Rarely saw such convoluted code. You show a sample of `sna.txt` but in your code you do not use it at all. You `Get-Content $SNACFGPath` which is unkown and also `$snacomputers = '\\xxx\yyy\snacomputers.txt'`. Your code is quite ineffcient reading in whole files and then saving to file again, read the file in again etc. This isn't a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is helpful for you:

```
$sourceFilePath  = 'C:\test.txt'
$destFilePath    = 'C:\test1.txt'

$dt = New-Object system.Data.DataTable
[void]$dt.Columns.Add('WORKSTATION',[string]::empty.GetType() )
[void]$dt.Columns.Add('INSERT',[string]::empty.GetType() )

foreach($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines($sourceFilePath))
{
    if( $line ) {
        if( $line -like '*WORKSTATION*' ) {
            $workstation = @( $line -split ' ' | ? { $_ } )[1]
            $rows = $dt.Select("WORKSTATION = '$workstation'")

            if( $rows.Count -lt 1 ) {
                $newRow = $dt.NewRow()
                $newRow.WORKSTATION = $workstation
                $newRow.INSERT      = ''
                [void]$dt.Rows.Add( $newRow )
            }

        }
        elseif( $line -like '*INSERT*' ) {
            $insert = (@( $line -split ':' | ? { $_ } )[1]).Trim(' \')
            $rows   = $dt.Select("WORKSTATION = '$workstation'")

            if( $rows.Count -gt 0 ) {
                if( !(($rows[0]).INSERT).Contains( $insert ) ) {
                    ($rows[0]).INSERT += ',' + $insert
                    [void]$dt.AcceptChanges()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

$dt.Select("", "WORKSTATION") | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Select -Skip 1 | % { $_.Replace('"','').Replace(',,',',').Trim(',') } | Out-File $destFilePath -Force
```

Comment: Thank you. I will give it ago.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is ineffcient and I'll work on it to make it nicer and more effcient.

However, changing from out-file to add-content makes a big different. It now takes only few minutes.